# Strange Message when open a java web application with self-signed applets

Tags: java, applet

I have made ​​web application that uses java applets, from today when i open the application java show me a sign that says:

"the execution of applications from unknown publishers will be block because are potentially unsafe and presents a segurity risk"

and asks me to accept the risk and confirm if I want to run it.

The applet is self-signed and the java version is 7u25

why is showing me this now?
How I can do to get back to normal?

Comment: Perhaps [*Firefox's Blocked-By-Default Java Isn't Going Down Well*](http://news.slashdot.org/story/13/10/23/0044227).

Comment: you're rigth, but what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do?

As a security measure, the Java plugin is [disabled](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2013/102213-firefox-java-275087.html?hpg1=bn) by default in recent versions of Firefox, but you can enable the plugin under `Add-ons > Plugins`. Consider doing so *temporarily* for trusted applets.